# I don't understand what a Pythagorean closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is; how are these definitions equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have two definitions of the said field.
And frankly I don't see why one is equivalent to the other. It just doesn't add up.

Let's look at wikipedia's definition.

> In algebra, a Pythagorean field is a field in which every sum of two squares is a square.

So, say there are $a,b \in K$ where $K $ is the Pythagorean closure (of $\mathbb{Q}$) These numbers must have the property $a^2+b^2=c^2$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Q}$. Yes? $K$ is a collection of all such numbers, so if I choose any two elements in $K$, square and sum them, I get a square number. Sure.

But how is this from Ian Stewart's book the same?

> The Pythagorean closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the smallest subfield $K \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ such that $z \in K \Rightarrow \pm \sqrt{z} \in K$

No, I don't think they're the same. How can the latter be deduced from the former? Or are Pythagorean FIELDS and CLOSURE different things? This is utterly confusing and I don't understand it at all.

Comment: I don't know this particular notion but in general, "closure" means the smallest structure with some property. Here "Pythagorean closure" means the smallest extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ that is also a Pythagorean field.

Comment: That being said, it doesn't seem obvious that they are equivalent... Is the sentence from Stewart a definition or a proposition/theorem?

Comment: In the first definition the elements can all be real. In the second they cannot be.

Comment: It is a definition from Stewart's Galois Theory 4th edition. And the fact that they're allowed to be complex doesn't seem to be the only difference.

Comment: To expand a little on André's comment, note that the reals are Pythagorean, so the Pythagorean closure of $\mathbb Q$ contradicts Stewart's claim. The Wikipedia entry on Pythagorean fields has a good list of references that you may want to explore.