# Pythagorean Closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is extremely obscure. Can someone give a clear answer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

My previous question didn't get me a definite answer. I've refined it so with a specific example so it might help someone clear my confusion.

In Stewart's book, The Pythagorean closure is defined as

$\textbf{Definition}$ The Pythagorean Closure $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the smallest subfield $K \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ with the property

$$z \in K \Rightarrow  \pm \sqrt{z} \in K   \tag{Eq1}$$

I am not clear about what this definition is saying. Specifically, in the proof of the theorem (7.11 in Stewart Galois theory 4th Ed)

$\textbf{Theorem}$
A complex number $\alpha$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$ if and only if there is a tower of field extensions
$$\mathbb{Q}=K_0 \subseteq K_1 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq =K_n \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$$

such that

$$   [K_{j+1}:K_j]=2$$
for $0 \leq j \leq n-1$

$\textbf{proof}$

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose that such a tower exists. We prove by induction on $j$ that $K_j \subseteq \mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$. This is clear for $j=0$.

$\textbf{Note}$:Since I am not clear of the definition of $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$, I do not truly understand why $K_0=\mathbb{Q} \in \mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$. But since Stewart says that $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$ is the intersection of all subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying Eq1, for now I am taking it for granted and acquiesced.

Now $K_{j+1}$ is an extension of $K_j$ with degree $2$ so $K_j+1=K_j(\beta)$ where the minimum polynomial of $\beta$ over $K_j$ is a quadratic. Since quadratics can be solved by extracting square roots, $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$, so $K_{j+1} \in \subseteq \mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$. (Pause proof)

The statement $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$ is what I am not convinced with. So, if $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$, then $\pm \sqrt{\beta} \in \mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$. I do not see $\textit{what}$ fact assures this. I'll be more specific with a break down of how my train of thought is running now and where my confusion is coming from.

So I know $m$ is a quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=m(x)$. Where, $m(\beta)=0$.
Thus $a \beta^2+b \beta+c=0$. I believe completing the square gives,

$$\Big(\beta + \frac{b}{2a}\Big)^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$$

So,

$$\beta =\pm \sqrt{\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}}-\frac{b}{2a}$$

Coinciding with the result using the quadratic formula(I did this since the proof says "extract square roots"). Hence,

$$\pm \sqrt{\beta} = \pm \sqrt{\pm \sqrt{\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}}-\frac{b}{2a}} \tag{Eq2}$$

Which looks ugly. What assures Eq2 $\in \mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$? I get stuck answering this; simply because, there is no further information given in the definition to determine whether or not a particular number is in or not in $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$.

$\textbf{Question }$:Like in this case, I have $\beta$. And $\pm \sqrt{\beta}$ is Eq2. Is Eq2 in $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$? It is IF $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$ but then I must turn to and how can I answer the question "is $\beta$ in $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$"? Well, if $\beta^2 \in \mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$ then it is, but then what assures me that $\beta^2 \in \mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$? What is the determining factor? I do not know the particular form of the elements of $\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$ or anything. And all I know about $\beta$ in this particular case is that it's implied that it's  in $\mathbb{C}$.
Essentially, I do not understand the statement "Since quadratics can be solved by extracting square roots, $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{Py}}$"

I suspect my question is caused by my lack of comfortability and understanding of the definition given by Stewart. Further, "Pythagorean Closure of $\mathbb{Q}$" doesn't seem like a common notion on the internet; Pythagorean field is the most hit I have which, Wikipedia claims

"In algebra, a Pythagorean field is a field in which every sum of two squares is a square"

And I cannot link THIS definition to the one Stewart is giving. So I have assumed they may be related, but different.

Comment: The link to your earlier question is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706016/i-dont-understand-what-a-pythagorean-closure-of-mathbbq-is-how-are-these).

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if someone can specifically answer the $\textbf{Question}$ in this post with detail.

Comment: Regarding your **Note**, every subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$. In addition, there is at least one subfield $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$ having the property that $z \in K \implies \pm\sqrt{z} \in K$, namely $K=\mathbb{C}$ itself.

Comment: Yes, that's where the "since" bit comes from; As they are intersections of $\mathbb{C}$ subfields, apparently. I don't see how this is equivalent to the definition though, which is one of my issues.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

- $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}^{Py}$

is equivalent to the statement

- for every subfield $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ having the property that $z \in K \implies \pm \sqrt{z} \in K$ we have $\beta \in K$.

Let's prove that $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}^{Py} \implies \pm\sqrt{\beta} \in \mathbb{Q}^{Py}$.

Assume $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}^{Py}$. Assume $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ is any subfield having the property that $z \in K \implies \pm \sqrt{z} \in K$. Since $\mathbb{Q}^{Py}$ is the intersection of all such subfields, it follows that $\beta \in K$. By assumption on $K$ it follows that $\pm \sqrt{\beta} \in K$. Since $K$ was arbitrary (amongst all subfields having the property that $z \in K \implies \pm \sqrt{z} \in K$), it follows that $\pm\sqrt{\beta}$ is in the intersection of all those $K$. That intersection equals $\mathbb{Q}^{Py}$. We have proved that $\pm\sqrt{\beta} \in \mathbb{Q}^{Py}$.

In your example, you are starting with the assumption that the coefficients $a,b,c$ are all in $\mathbb{Q}^{Py}$. And in (Eq2) you have written out an explicit expression for $\pm\sqrt{\beta}$ formed from $a,b,c$ using the operations of arithmetic and square root. But  $\mathbb{Q}^{Py}$ is closed under the operations of arithmetic because it is a field, and I've just shown it is also closed under the operation of square root. It follows that $\pm \sqrt{\beta} \in \mathbb{Q}^{Py}$.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, where did I assume that $a,b,c$ are in the Pythagorean Closure of $\mathbb{Q}$? I suppose it was implied somewhere in the proof since it isn't explicitly stated, but I don't know where and how.

Comment: It's where you wrote "...the minimum polynomial of $\beta$ over $K_j$ is quadratic ... So I know $m$ is a quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c = 0 = m(x)$. Where $m(\beta)=0$". In other words, by the context, $m(x)$ is the minimum polynomial of $\beta$ over $K_j$. And so its coefficients $a,b,c$ are elements of $K_j$. And so by applying the induction hypothesis $K_j \subset \mathbb{Q}^{Py}$, it follows that $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}^{Py}$.